# Robolectric shadow context not picking up product flavor package name

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric, android-build

I'm using Gradle to specify some product flavors in my build, but the package name being found by the shadow application's context isn't the custom one, it's the one in the default manifest. The built apk, though, reports the custom package name.

From the test:

```
    final Context context = Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getApplicationContext();
    System.out.println("Package name is: " + context.getPackageName());
```

According to [http://tools.android.com/tech-docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-system-concepts#TOC-Product-Flavors):

> Overriding the package name of a flavor has no impact on where the R
>   class is generated. This is applied when the final APK is created
>   only.

...which sounds like the flavor is only applied for part of the build process. Any ideas for how to get it to use the flavor when building the tests too?

Comment: This is not perfect solution - you can copy, modify AndroidManifest.xml and point Robolectric to it

Comment: Like by overriding the TestRunner?

Comment: I would prefer that gradle do AndroidManifest manipulation and I'm not sure if it is possible point Robolectric to this file without extending TestRunner. If it is not possible you should extend it but still manifest manipulation should be done in gradle where you have knowledge about desired package name